Need Guidance with Independent Inspection Forms in REDCap
I'm new to REDCap and I'm hoping to get some guidance. I'd like to create six independent forms for various inspections (cemeteries, tire centers, schools, mosquito detection...). My goal is to have each form function individually, and I'd prefer to disable the "Save & Next Record" option at the end to prevent users from accidentally creating multiple entries.
Could you advise on the most appropriate method to achieve this setup using project creation, survey settings, and potentially branching logic? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
I've tried looking through the project settings and survey settings, but I haven't been able to find a clear option to disable "Save & Next Record."
What I expected:
To find a setting or configuration that would remove the "Save & Next Record" button from the form.
Users would only have a "Save" option, finalizing data entry for that specific inspection.

It's impossible to disable to the "Save & Go to Next Record" button. What you can do as an alternative is use form display logic to disable the other inspection forms until certain conditions are met. You can also utilize locking and unlocking privileges (in User Rights menu) to "finalize" data entry for a specific inspection, so that users cannot change or accidentally override a completed inspection form. Without having more details about your use case(s), that's as detailed as I can offer.

I'll look into those options. Thank you very much Cristian!
